# Java RMI - Object of Class extending UnicastRemoteObject keeps JVM alive

Tags: java, rmi

I am currently trying to understand how to work with Java RMI and `UnicastRemoteObject` to enable 2-way communication (Client invokes Server-Methods and Server invokes Client-Methods).

I have a RMI Server application creating a registry and binding a service. A client extending `UnicastRemoteObject` and implementing `Remote` can be passed as a reference to the server. The server can then also invoke methods on the client object.

Minimal working example:

## Server

### Server Main

```java
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        var service = new ServiceImpl();
        var serviceSkel = (Service) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, 0);
        var url = String.format("rmi://%s%s", "localhost:1099", "/Service");
        Naming.rebind(url, serviceSkel);
    }
}
```

### Service Interface

```java
public interface Service extends Remote {
    void WriteOnServer(Client c) throws RemoteException;
}
```

### Service Implementation

```java
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{
    @Override
    public void WriteOnServer(Client c) throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("client executed this method");
        c.WriteOnClient();
    }
}
```

## Client

### Client Interface

```java
public interface Client extends Remote {
    void WriteOnClient() throws RemoteException;
}
```

### Client Implementation + Main

```java
public class ClientImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Client {
    protected ClientImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void WriteOnClient() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.println("server executed this method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException {
        var client = new ClientImpl();
        var service = (Service) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Service");
        service.WriteOnServer(client);

        // with following line: client application exits cleanly
        // without following line: client application never exits
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(client, false);
    }
}
```

### Problem / Question

Everything works as expected meaning...

1. Server starts and binds service to registry
2. Client starts, retrieves service object from registry
3. Client invokes the service remote method and passes itself as argument
4. Server prints to console and then invokes the remote method on the client reference
5. Client prints to console

... but the client application never exits the JVM if I do not manually unexport the client object because (i guess) RMI is keeping a non-daemon thread alive waiting for further remote invocations.

Is this expected?
Do I have to store a list of all exported Objects and call `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(Object, Boolean)` on all of them manually?

I also tried to implement `Unreferenced` in `ClientImpl` but the method `unreferenced()` is never called:

```java
public class ClientImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Client, Unreferenced {

.
.
.

    @Override
    public void unreferenced() {
        try {
            UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, true);
        } catch (NoSuchObjectException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The client becomes unreferenced when the server releases the client stub, which depends on the DGC interval.  When that happens you can unexport it. You don't need a list. NB (1) The result of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` should be stored in a static variable. NB (2) The result of `exportObject()` is not a skeleton but a stub.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Suppose my approach to implement 2 way communication is correct: how would a clean client application shut down look like? how can I instruct the server to release the stub on my exported object since I am about to shut down the application?

Comment: Add a remote method, `logout()` for example, that causes the server to do that. Then either wait for `unreferenced()` to fire and forcibly unexport the object then, or unexport it immediately after the logout call if you trust the server not to be about to make another callback.

Comment: I am not sure what the `logout()` method shall do. in above example, the server does not hold any reference (variable) to the client object - it is just a method argument which the server invokes a method on.